# how to use a hook and avoid a loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want the `fetchTasks()` function to be called when I start the component, I know that `componentDidMount()` is used with classes, but in this way `useEffect` is used, when I use it, I enter a loop, although it does not send me warnings or errors it sends constant requests to API.

```
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

const fetchTasks = (e) => {
        fetch('/api/tasks')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            setTasks(data)
            console.log(tasks);
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }
    
        useEffect(() => {
            fetchTasks();
        })
```

I only want to **get the API data once** when rendering the component.

*Would it be correct to take advantage of this loop to use it as a socket with the API?*

Thank you very much, I haven't been in React long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use square brackets in useEffect like

```
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchTasks();
    },[])
```

If you want to call this again on change of anystate then call like

```
    useEffectt(() => {
        fetchTasks();
    },[state_variable_name])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, I would like to know more about this, is there any documentation that I can refer to?

Comment: The way of explaining in ths blog i find really helpful.Hope it will help you to    https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-useeffect-explanation/#:~:text=useEffect(callback%2C%20dependencies)%20is,being%20props%20or%20state%20values.

Answer (score 1):

To only fetch your data onces inside `useEffect` you have to provide an empty dependancy array.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetchTasks();
}, [])
```